# Google STT using Google Voice Search and saving the audio

Tags: android, search, record, voice

I'm using the Speech-To-Text Feature of Google Voice Search:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "de-DE");
```

After some search using Google, I found this piece of code to get the Audio of the speech:

```
        intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true);
        intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "Audio / AMR");
```

For some reason, this is not working for me. In onActivityResult(), I print data.getDataString() and get a nullpointer-Exception. data.getData normally returns the URI to the audio file.

```
at MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:104)
Stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getDataString()' on a null object reference
```

How comes the data.getData() is null?

Further I tried to recorde with MediaRecorder simultaneously, but this didnt work since Android does not support 2 channel recording.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Changing to "AUDIO/AMR" (without spaces) didn't solve it.